# Configure pip to install everything as with --user

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to make `pip install` always run as if I gave the `--user` command? I have to type it every time, especially when copying commands from instructions, and it is tedious to do. I don't really see a good reason to ever install things as root when I can just install with `--user`.

Configuration is preferred to simple bash alias.

Comment: The distinction between user-local and system-wide installation was more important before virtual environments became widespread.

Answer (score 8):

Add `user = true` to your [pip configuration file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file). Specifically, it would go in the `[install]` section:

```
[install]
user = true
```

Comment: `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` doesn't exist on my system.

Comment: create a file in that path if it does not exist.

Comment: On windows, it works as well when pip config file is %appdata%/pip/pip.ini

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to editing pip.conf: export `PIP_USER=true` in your environment, such as in your .bashrc.

All [the configuration options](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables) can also be set in the environment.